# Old PVC pipe arches / bows out of the ground

Tags: pvc

The concern is that 30 year old PVC pipe is now arching out of the ground and will be damaged by a lawn mower or similar strike.  I think they may have been deployed for defunct sprinklers, but not certain.

Front side of wooden fence:
[image]

Back side of fence:

[image]

Is there a clever / simple remedy?  I would think I am not the first to observe such a problem.  I would like to avoid cutting the pipe if possible.

Update:  Other pipes were found, which provided the opportunity to pin the wayward PVC with zip ties:

[image]

Pinning the PVC with zip ties and buried:

[image]

Comment: Are both sides of the fence on your property?

Comment: Yes, both sides of the fence are on the property.

Comment: You need to follow the pipe to an end and figure out what's inside.  Could be for water, or for low voltage garden lights, or some non-compliant AC power cable run.  Might even be a phone wire.

Comment: Yeah, the answers below are assuming that something important is (or isn't) in those pipes.  There's absolutely no point in digging up your yard to repair pipes you don't use.  If they're really for sprinklers that don't exist any more and you don't care about then fixing this is pointless.  You **need** to discover what's in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already damaged by the sunlight, I'd say.

Rip it out, or dig deep enough to bury it properly, but likely already damaged sufficiently that preserving it is of dubious value.

Burying it properly is simple, but more tedious than clever.

Answer (score 4):

Cut it back to where it's not damaged by sunlight, cap it off, and bury it.

This way you can avoid the tripping/splintering hazard and preserve it for un-defunctification in the future. It would be trivial to bring this pipe back to life using a coupling.